# Unable to use pymssql in Python 3.5

Tags: python, pip, python-module, pyd

I have installed `pymssql` using `pip` however It is never found when I try to import into a project.

I get the error, `No module found 'pymssql'`

I have attempted to copy the `.pyd` file (`pymssql-2.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.pyd`) to the project directory and this is still a problem

So. just using...

```
import pymssql
```

...results in the module not being found, If I try to reinstall through pip it states it is installed and requirement is already satisfied.

How can i get this useable

I am using Python 3.5 and Windows 10
Python is installed in `Appdata/Local/Programs/Python35`
Modules are installed `Appdata/Roaming/Python35/site-packages/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the `.whl` file manually from the Pymssql website resolved the issue and allowed me to use the module in my project!